# Why does a continue in this ForEach-Object loop cause Powershell to error

Tags: powershell, break, control-flow, continue

When piping the output of a command to a `ForEach-Object` loop in PowerShell, using a `continue` statement causes it to error out.

Works as expected:

```
ipconfig | ForEach-Object {
  $_
}
```

Errors:

```
ipconfig | ForEach-Object {
  $_
  continue
}
```

The error is

```
Program 'ipconfig.exe' failed to run: System error.At C:\Users\test\ps.ps1:1 char:1
+ nslookup google.com | ForEach-Object {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At C:\Users\test\ps.ps1:1 char:1
+ nslookup google.com | ForEach-Object {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

This seems to happen with any external command, such as `nslookup` and `net`

I thought maybe this had to do with some type conversion, but the object inside the loop is always a string. Saving the command output to a variable, and then doing a `$var | ForEach-Object` works.

Comment: What's the point of using `continue` as the very last statement in the block?

Comment: There is no point, but it's to keep the minimal reproducible example short and easy

Answer (score 3):

`continue` statements in PowerShell can only be used within loop constructs. While `ForEach-Object` seems like a loop, it's not.

In PowerShell, you can technically use `continue` outside of a loop, but it causes PowerShell to not find a loop, and just terminate the current runspace.<sup>1</sup>

This means PowerShell can actually terminate the caller<sup>1</sup>, and looking at the callstack, that caller is the "parent" line and so it is terminated.

Callstack right before the `continue` executes:

```
ScriptLineNumber : 4
Position         : continue
FunctionName     : <ScriptBlock>


ScriptLineNumber : 1
Position         : net help | ForEach-Object {
                       $_.GetType()
                       continue
                   }
FunctionName     : <ScriptBlock>
```

Instead, use a `return` statement.

---

Reference

1 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Nice; worth nothing that the same applies analogously to [`break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Break#do-not-use-break-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap)

Comment: More specifically: When `break` or `continue` are used in a statement that isn't loop-like (doesn't itself support these keywords), PowerShell _walks up the call stack_ to find a loop, and breaks out of / continues the first one found (which may be unrelated to what you're trying to do). Only if no loop is found anywhere on the call stack is the runspace quietly exited. E.g., `do { 1..10 | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -gt 5) { break }; $_ } } while ($false)` causes the `break` to exit the enclosing `do` loop, a technique that can be leveraged to exit a pipeline prematurely.